# Can't import pyo: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, import, python-import, pyo

I'm trying to import pyo in python3.7 and I'm not getting any results. This is what happens when I try to run the command:

```
>>> import pyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyo\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .lib import analysis as analysis
  File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyo\lib\analysis.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ._core import *
  File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyo\lib\_core.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .._pyo import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple versions of pyo but I get the same result. Can anyone try and debug this error so I can import the module, thank you

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install pyo`to install pyo? Your error can be based on which environment/OS You use.

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install pyo`to install pyo? Your error can be based on which environment/OS You use.

Comment: Yes I have tried installing it and reinstalling it and i cannot import it